# if i make an API call it returns me with HTML code in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, http, dart, flutter-http

I am using `HTTP package` for making API requests but when I make a request it returns me with `Html response`.

```dart
import 'package:clima/services/location.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocation();
  }

  void getLocation() async {
    Location location = new Location();
    await location.getCurrentLocation();

    print(location.latitude);
    print(location.longitude);
  }

  void getData() async {
    final url =
        'samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22';
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    print(response.body);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getData();
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

here when I print `response body` it returns me with HTML source code instead of 'JSON'

this is what I get as a response...

[image: an image of the response text]

I need help with getting a valid JSON response from the API and not an HTML response.

**EDIT:** it is now solved!

Comment: What books did you read about HTTP?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch none actually I am new to flutter and started learning about making API calls with flutter

Comment: Why can't you read books about HTTP? These are printed on paper. An old one is [HTTP developer's handbook](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1028975.HTTP_Developer_s_Handbook) but you could find newer ones.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch recently flutter has changed the syntax of 'http' and I don't know how to use it

Comment: I never heard about flutter, but did you read its documentation?

Comment: yup but still i am not getting what I want

Comment: And what books did you read about HTTP? These are printed on paper, and have more than a hundred pages.

Comment: there is no point in reading books as syntax is changed just a few months back and books are printed years ago.

Comment: HTTP did not evolve that much.... [RFC7540](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540) has been written 6 years ago. Of course, you could print it with your printer

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch please read the documentation and if you find any useful thing I can try then do suggest

Comment: No, I read documentation related to the software I am writing, and I write documentation related to the software I am writing. I am not writing your code, and I never heard of flutter

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch do you write in `flutter`

Comment: No, I don't. I use (and contributed to) [libonion](https://coralbits.com/static/onion/). But I did read documentation related to HTTP.

Comment: i am working with `http package` for flutter and which is way different than yours

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Patrick yes it is now solved!

Comment: @vanditvasa what was the solution

Comment: Have you solved this? how?

Comment: @GHPrakash it isn't solved yet!

Comment: ok, If solved please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is not complete.

Change this code

```
void getData() async {
    final url =
        'samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22';
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    print(response.body);
  }
```

to this,

```
void getData() async {
    final url =
        'https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22';
    http.Response response = await http.get(url));
    print(response.body);
  }
```

Let us know if it worked.

Comment: what error? edit and add in your question... otherwise try http instead of https

Comment: check I have edited the code. inside http.get() only use url, do not need Uri.parse() ... just use http.get(url) .. let me know if it works

Comment: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri' => this error is being thrown

Comment: please check the updated code in my answer. I removed that http.get(Uri.parse()) ... use only http.get(url). ... it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232379/discussion-between-ratnadeep-chakraborty-and-vandit-vasa).

Comment: Have similar problem with this question, thank you for your help good sir.